# AngularJs directive to include youtube url

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

My requirement is to create a template for video, image or note. So, I created a directive for video and embed youtube url. I am not seeing any error and console see correct url. But on UI is putting blank.

Directive

```
<ve-iframe video="item"></ve-iframe>

app.directive('veIframe', function($compile, $sce){
        var linker = function(scope, element, attr) {
            var youtubeUrl= 'http://www.youtube.com/embed/';
            var embed = youtubeUrl+scope.video.id.videoId;
            console.log(embed);
            var template = '<iframe id="player" type="text/html" width="520" height="300" ng-src="{{embed}}" frameborder="0"></iframe>';
            element.html(template).show();

            $compile(element.contents())(scope);
        }
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            link: linker,
            scope: {
                video: '='
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Did you white list resource?

Answer (score 0):

My mistake, below line of code fixed the problem

scope.embed = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(youtubeUrl+scope.video.id.videoId);